# jrebel - all classes reloading

Tags: java, jrebel

Recently jrebel has started reloading all of the classes in our project when we make a jersey request as well as when we shut down.  It doesn't seem to be every request but if you wait a while between requests it is almost guaranteed to happen.

It just loops over every class in the project and reloads it - I had to bump the permgen because it was blowing past that.

Any ideas on what to check that may have changed that would cause this to happen all of the sudden?

Comment: jrebel had a release on 4/19, did you auto-update?  I haven't yet so can't confirm if it's a bug in that release.  Another option is that your IDE is building more than you expected on a change, but not sure why that would suddenly change.

Comment: we did not download the update but it's worked fine with the version we ahve anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was a maven issue in the way we were installing a jar that was not part of a repo.  It was getting a strange dependency that was causing a circular reference which meant that when any class changed it refreshed all of them thus causing jrebel to reload everything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you recompile the whole application classes before the request? JRebel will only pick up and updated those classes which timestamp was changed.

Updating the classes will not start on its own - something should trigger the process, so waiting between the requests doesn't make much sense. Unless you have some daemon process sending the requests to the service.

Enable JRebel logging with -Drebel.log=true and send the jrebel.log file to support - it can be traced then.

Comment: we did not re-compile the whole app.  In fact we didn't do anything, just make another request after editing one file.

Comment: well it can easily be your IDE that maybe thinks that it is too smart and makes a clean build on your project